# Javascript preg_match-like example for price

Tags: javascript, regex

I need javascript regular expression example.
I want to let insert just values like 12.15 or 15,12... (for me need not exactly that values, but decimal values with dot or comma)
How to format a regular expression for it?

Acceptable values: 12.15, 15.15, 13.14

Forbidden values: 12,15, 15,15, 15,ads15

Comment: for me need to check if value in text field is decimal

Comment: Please give a list of ok and not ok values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a regex that matches only correclty formatted prices with 2-digit cents values, this will work:

```
/^-?[0-9]+\.[0-9][0-9]$/
```

pass it a string that and it will match if the string (the whole string) is a correct price, with exactly 2 decimal places.

Note the `/^...` and and `...$/`.  They ensure that the entire string matches, or not at all.

Note also the `-?`. This matches negative prices.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need regex for this kind of thing, try parseFloat

```
var float = parseFloat("12.15");
```

if the argument is not a valid number, `parseFloat()` returns `NaN`

Comment: @DonatasVeikutis no offense but I seriously have difficulty trying to understand what you mean :(, could you try to rephrase it? I'd love to help you :)

Comment: in example if I have value in text field like "12.15" or "12,15", for me need to check if that line contains decimal number with dot or comma :)

Comment: so both `12.15` and `12,15` are valid? You just need to know whether it contains comma or dot, yes?